# How to center pseudo element ::after border in a div?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

i want to ask you. I'm trying to create a border using pseudo element (after). I want to place a border in the middle of the div box that I have created, without setting (top, bottom) and (left, right). Can it be automated in the middle?

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/vYLqWJd)

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

```
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  
  &::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/cbkK4k5 - like that?

Comment: no, it same like mine

Comment: you have like this - https://ibb.co/px1SMBM

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can:

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Allthough I don't completely understand why you wouldn't want to use top, right, bottom, left values. With transform, you can't automate it ALWAYS. You'll have to set it to half the height of the box. With a top value, you could just set it to 50%.

Comment: i want the border like this https://i.imgur.com/BYR214t.png

Comment: Ooooooh. That makes MUCH more sense hahahaha.

Best option is a div within a div. I'll update my comment.

Comment: Updated, but again, would be way easier when you use top, right, bottom, left values. Is this for a challenge or something?

Comment: no, i just want to know. the box that I made isn't like that. And i want to ask you, when I hover, the box will show a black gradient layer with opacity 0.5 and border moved like this image? https://imgur.com/82kiRxn

Answer (score 0):

I've used percentages for the `top` and `left` and than correect the positioning with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` so its in the middle

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
 
}

.box::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways....!!

```
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  
  &::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid blue;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
  }
}
```

Another way...without using positions.

```
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  display: flex;
  
  &::after{
    content:'';
    border:2px solid blue;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: if the display box is flex it will have an effect to the div inside

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  
  }
  
.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 3%;
    left: 4%;
    height: 93%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox on the `.box` element to center its contents. Just make sure no other position property is set on the `::after` pseudo-element:

```
.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```